# Qt5 with MacOS : How to add entries in the application menu?

Tags: macos, qt5

I'm writing an app using Qt5. That app runs on Window, Linux and now on MacOS.

In order to make sure my app meets the apple's requirements, I would like to add entries in the application menu (preferences, about...).

[image]

Does anyone know how to do so ?

An [old doc about Qt4.8](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/mac-differences.html) describes that the menu is handle by Qt but it doesn't describe what to do.

Comment: Use the [QAction::MenuRole property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#menuRole-prop) to describe what role the action serves in the application menu on Mac OS X.

Comment: @Linville: It works ! Thanks. Feel free to post an official answer so I can check it.

Answer (score 4):

I saw this question and was looking for an answer. The comments were helpful, but here is a more complete code example that should help others out.

**mainwindow.h: Add these include statements**

```
#include <QMenu>
#include <QAction>

...

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QMenu *mainMenu;
    QAction *aboutAction;
```

**mainwindow.cpp: initializer function**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    this->aboutAction = new QAction(0);
    this->aboutAction->setMenuRole(QAction::AboutRole);
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->mainMenuBar = new QMenuBar(0);
    this->mainMenu = new QMenu(0);
    this->mainMenuBar->addMenu(this->mainMenu);
    this->mainMenu->addAction(this->aboutAction);
    this->setMenuBar(this->mainMenuBar);
}
```

Using QT 5.3.2 and Snow Leopard OS X 10.6.8, QT Creator 3.0.1.

Since you are using the `AboutRole`, there is no need to specify the QString parameter of QAction. It automatically defaults to what you want.

[image: About Menu for Mac OS X using QT Creator]

Comment: You will have to connect the About QAction to a function to display a modal window if you want the actual functionality.